# Show spinner in EditText using "setCompoundDrawables" and TextWatcher

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I'm trying to achieve this effect on a EditText:

[image: Spinner]

Using `TextWatcher` and `setCompoundDrawables`,

This is my code:

```
    searchEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_search);

    searchEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
    {
        CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(800, 800)
        {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() 
            {
                Log.i("SearchActivity", "searching..");
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) 
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
        {
            timer.cancel();
            timer.start();

            //This is not working:
            searchEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_call, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) 
        {
            searchEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    });
```

In the code I've commented what is not working: "// This is not working"

I have two questions:

1. What drawable should I use for a animated spinner/loading? android.R.drawable.**what**?
2. With the testing icon I've chosen (ic_menu_call) is not working. I'm always seeing the search icon and never the "call" icon.

I want that while the user is typing he sees the other non-search icon (the spinner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `beforeTextChanged` and `onTextChanged` happens too fast that the `EditText` doesnt have time you change drawable from one to another thus giving you only the last drawable that is added which is the `ic_menu_search`

**solution:**

use your timer instead to change drawable to give time to edditText to change drawable inside it.

**sample:**

```
final EditText searchEditText = new EditText(this);

    searchEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
    {
        CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(1000, 800)
        {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
            {
                searchEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_call, 0, 0, 0);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() 
            {
                Log.i("SearchActivity", "searching..");
                searchEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search, 0, 0, 0);
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) { }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
        {
            timer.cancel();
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) { }
    });
```

As you can see I set your timer duration to **1 second** so the `EditText` has time to change back to another drawable.

For question 1 and 2, you cant add `View` to the `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` that it only need drawable or bitmap from your drawable folder or android default drawable folder.

Comment: the first part works perfect, thanks. Although I'm not following the last part: So I can't put a animated loading icon inside the EditText?

Comment: @sports yes you are right. `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` only accepts bitmap from drawable folder, `Drawables` means plain image and not animated.

Comment: Ah! bummer. So I will have to use a Layout and mimic the borders of the editText, or something like that.

Comment: @sports +1 this post if it helps thank you. you can use `relative layou`t which support **z-axis** means a view on top of another view.

Comment: I've seen some examples using relative layout and it seems easy to put the icon at the end of the editText, but.. if I choose to put it to the left, what can I do to give the text within the editText some margin?